# nginx: how to divide /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf ?

Tags: nginx

looking for a way to divide /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf, something like per site. Any idea? 
current file looks like this:

```
 upstream Master_MAT {
    server 172.18.0.3:8080;
  }

  upstream Master_PAT {
    server 172.18.0.4:8080;
 }
 server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  warn;

    root /etc/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.php;

    #charset koi8-r;

   location / {
    root /etc/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri /$uri $uri/ =404;
   }

   location /Master_MAT {
        proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
        proxy_pass http://Master_MAT/Master_MAT;
#       proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host    $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
   location /Master_PAT {
        proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
        proxy_pass http://Master_PAT/Master_PAT;
#       proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host    $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

Is there a way to put the Master_MAT in different file? Tried to use 'include' yet failed.

THX

Answer (score 1):

Most people recommend using the `sites-enabled` and `sites-available` [approach](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-nginx-web-server-on-a-virtual-private-server):

```
http {
    …
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Now you can leave 'disabled' sites in `sites-available` and move them into the `sites-enabled` folder when you want it to be in use.

This is a wildcard so you can just create new `.conf` files for each site and it will load them automatically.

Here's an example of what would go inside `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com`

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Comment: not sure I've understood how each file should look like. Can you please be more detailed ? 
THX

Comment: I added an example. What goes inside the server block is 100% up to your use-case and website... but you would wrap everything in a `server{}` block

Comment: When I'm trying to create more than one file I get the following error: 
2018/03/08 13:26:52 [emerg] 1028#1028: a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/conf/New3.conf:2
nginx: [emerg] a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/conf/New3.conf:2
-- Any idea ??
THX

Comment: You might need to specify the domain. I'm going to guess because you have conflicting host+port matches. This should be a separate question though because it's getting into the internals of Nginx.